# Unable to send files through unix scipt in docker to AWS S3

Tags: python-3.x, docker, amazon-s3, dockerfile

I have one unix shell script in docker which has below command to send files to AWS S3 bucket. When I run the docker container and when the shell script executed it throws an error saying command not found. But the same script when run through local machine it runs. Only while running via docker t s giving me error. Docker image consists of essential python libraries.

Below is my docker image:

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.6-slim

USER root

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
# RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install ipython
RUN pip3 install numpy
RUN pip3 install pandas
RUN pip3 install scikit-learn
RUN pip3 install BeautifulSoup4 
RUN pip3 install scipy
RUN pip3 install lxml
RUN pip3 install boto3


RUN pip3 install awscli

EXPOSE 8888
```

Shell Script:

```
#Use curl to make PUT request. 
curl -L -X PUT -T "${sourceFilePath}" \
-H "Host: s3.amazonaws.com" \
-H "Date: ${dateValue}" \
-H "Content-Type: ${contentType}" \
-H "Authorization: AWS ${s3Key}:${signature}" \
https://s3.amazonaws.com/${bucket}/${filePathAtS3}
```

Error message in shell script:

```
src/assign_1/web_scrape.sh: line 39: curl: command not found
/src/assign_1/out/
date: invalid option -- 'j'
Try 'date --help' for more information.
/src/assign_1/web_scrape.sh: line 74: curl: command not found
```

Comment: You need to install cURL in the docker image!

Comment: I will try this @EugenRieck, will let you you know after trying.

Comment: Hi @EugenRieck the curl command worked but I am getting below error:


    % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
     16  1728    0   291    0     0   3086      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  3095
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>AWS authentication requires a valid Date or x-amz-date header</Message>

Comment: This means, that you send a wrong `Date` header - check the contents of `$dateValue`

Comment: It worked @EugenRieck, I just corrected the date variable and other inputs like credentials and now it is working, Thanks a lot.